# Iphone remove sub view

Tags: ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu, addsubview

I have a UINavigationController. On the right top i have a button on click of which i have to get a drop down table view. I created another UIViewController Class, with xib and added it as a subView to the current view. It should appear on 1st click and disappear on the 2nd click. This should happen for all click(open view and close view). I wrote this code but dont know where i'm going wrong. someone please help

```
-(void)modalTableView
{
tableView1 = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];

for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews)
{

    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]]) 
    {

         [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    else 
    {
        [self.view addSubview:tableView1.view];

    }
  }

}
```

What am i missing here?

**EDIT : TableViewController is the name of my UIViewController Class**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The clue is here

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews)
```

each subView is of class UIView and your test

```
isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]
```

is testing for class TableViewController

I would suggest a way of doing this would be by tagging the views that you add dynamically, with say 99 - and then in your loop you can identify those views by their tag.

eg.

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews)
{
    if (subView.tag == 99) 
    {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## Swift version

To remove a single subview:

```
subView.removeFromSuperview()
```

To remove all subviews:

```
for subView in self.subviews as [UIView] {
    subView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Source: [What is the best way to remove all views from parent view / super view?](https://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-all-subviews-from-parent-viewsuper-view/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) 
{

     [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I have a table view in my view also. So what this is doing is removing the tableview in my view and not the view controller i have added as asubview

Comment: Is your if condition working properly. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that should go some way to working - assuming that tableView1 is a retained @property (If not then maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026035/lazy-loading-in-objective-c) SO answer on lazy loading techniques is for you).

```
-(void)modalTableView
{
    if (tableView1 != nil)
    {
        tableView1 = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    if (tableView1.view.superview == nil)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:tableView1.view];
    } else
    {
        [tableView1.view removeFormSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: its just going to the second if loop where its adding a subview. n yes tableview1 is retained in its properties.

Comment: So, if it has a superview already you must have added it to something previously....keep checking you must be nearly there. Did you want to post your revised code now?