# Does Calling -init on super Chew Up Memory

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization

The following is commonplace in Objective-C.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Because `-init` is an instance method, it must be called on a valid instance of a class, and an instance of a class must be instantiated. This instantiation uses up memory. **Does calling `-init` on `super` use memory as it has to instantiate a new object to call the `init` method on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does calling -init on super use memory as it has to instantiate a new object to call the init method on?

No, because your premise is false. `super`, as the receiver of a message, is the *same object* as `self`; it's just a signal to the compiler to use [`objc_msgSendSuper()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSendSuper) instead of [`objc_msgSend()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend). The former starts method lookup with the superclass, but the instance that runs the method is still the same.

**No new instance is created by using the `super` keyword**.

Comment: "No new instance is created by using the super keyword", thankyou for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what's going on up the chain.

If it's simply "`[NSObject init]`", then nothing (obvious) is happening.

But if it's "`[BrianTracySuperAwesomeBaseClass init]`" with a lot of initialization and setting up various ivars and properties, then yes, you're using a bit of memory.

In general, you shouldn't load down your "`init`" methods with lots of stuff going on... instead you should rely on [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026035/lazy-loading-in-objective-c) or allocate-on-demand things for your Objective C objects.